# Basename quirks - what are they

Tags: perl

The documentation for File::Basename says

```
NOTE: "dirname()" and "basename()" emulate the behaviours, and quirks,
of the shell and C functions of the same name. See each function's
documentation for details.
```

What are these quirks?

Comment: Did you look at each functions documentation for details, or is your question really "How do I look at the documentation for shell and C functions?". When the answers you get are just copy-and-pasted excerpts from the docs, you have to consider if you are being a bit too lazy in doing your own work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the quirks are documented in the documentation for the Perl functions themselves.
http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/lib/File/Basename.pm#basename

> This function is provided for compatibility with the Unix shell
>   command basename(1). It does NOT always return the file name portion
>   of a path as you might expect. ... basename() returns the last level
>   of a filepath even if the last level is clearly directory. ... Also
>   note that in order to be compatible with the shell command, basename()
>   does not strip off a suffix if it is identical to the remaining
>   characters in the filename.

In other words, `basename("dir/")` is `"dir/"`, not `""`; and `basename("dir/.txt", ".txt")` is `".txt"`, not `""`.

http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/lib/File/Basename.pm#dirname
The quirks of `dirname` are much quirkier, and depend on the current value of `$File::Basename::Fileparse_fstype`. I'll just paste the code here, since it's short.

```
sub dirname {
    my $path = shift;
    my($type) = $Fileparse_fstype;
    if( $type eq 'VMS' and $path =~ m{/} ) {
        # Parse as Unix
        local($File::Basename::Fileparse_fstype) = '';
        return dirname($path);
    }

    my($basename, $dirname) = fileparse($path);

    if ($type eq 'VMS') { 
        $dirname ||= $ENV{DEFAULT};
    } elsif ($type eq 'MacOS') {
        if( !length($basename) && $dirname !~ /^[^:]+:\z/) {
            _strip_trailing_sep($dirname);
            ($basename,$dirname) = fileparse $dirname;
        }
        $dirname .= ":" unless $dirname =~ /:\z/;
    } elsif (grep { $type eq $_ } qw(MSDOS DOS MSWin32 OS2)) { 
        _strip_trailing_sep($dirname);
        unless( length($basename) ) {
            ($basename,$dirname) = fileparse $dirname;
            _strip_trailing_sep($dirname);
        }
    } elsif ($type eq 'AmigaOS') {
        if ( $dirname =~ /:\z/) { return $dirname }
        chop $dirname;
        $dirname =~ s{[^:/]+\z}{} unless length($basename);
    } else {
        _strip_trailing_sep($dirname);
        unless( length($basename) ) {
            ($basename,$dirname) = fileparse $dirname;
            _strip_trailing_sep($dirname);
        }
    }

    $dirname;
}


# Strip the trailing path separator.
sub _strip_trailing_sep  {
    my $type = $Fileparse_fstype;
    if ($type eq 'MacOS') {
        $_[0] =~ s/([^:]):\z/$1/s;
    } elsif (grep { $type eq $_ } qw(MSDOS DOS MSWin32 OS2)) { 
        $_[0] =~ s/([^:])[\\\/]*\z/$1/;
    } else {
        $_[0] =~ s{(.)/*\z}{$1}s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really helpful answer. As mentioned on other answer, I was looking in wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

The quirks are documented in the `man` pages for each function:

---

```
man dirname
```

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Print NAME with its trailing /component removed; if NAME contains
>   no /'s, output '.' (meaning the
>   current directory).
>
> **EXAMPLES**
>
> ```
> dirname /usr/bin/sort
>         Output "/usr/bin".
>
> dirname stdio.h
>         Output ".".
> ```

---

```
man basename
```

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Print NAME with any leading directory
>   components removed.  If specified,
>   also remove a trailing SUFFIX.
>
> **EXAMPLES**
>
> ```
> basename /usr/bin/sort
>         Output "sort".
>
> basename include/stdio.h .h
>         Output "stdio".
> ```

Comment: I believe this question is about the functions of the mentioned `File::Basename` perl module, not the shell programs themself, so their manpages won't necessarily answer that (although in this case they seem to, depending on your vendor).

Comment: @rafl : I understood 'See each function's documentation for details' to mean the shell documentation.

Comment: @Zaid me likewise. I went to `man basename` etc and didn't feel any the wiser.  The statement "See each function's documentation" is really confusing as it has just talked about C and shell functions.